# MySQL Error- What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: mysql, database

```
   CREATE TABLE myCTGlobalFootprint (
         geoID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
         geoName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (geoID)
    );


INSERT INTO myCTGlobalFootprint 
     (geoName)

VALUES 
     ('Canada'),
     ('United States'),
     ('Europe'),
     ('International Misc.');
```

It's throwing an error at line 15... any insight would be DEEPLY APPRECIATED!!

Comment: I've tried your code and found out that there is no error at all. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb74ab/1/0

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!!!

http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

I'm utilizing this validator to go through my scripts (I'm in a position where I can't access my shiny editor atm), it gives a vague warning that I need to examine where the query changes from the end of the table declaration to the insert statement. They validate independently, however.

Comment: You people are gods. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: Also, Rigel1121, SQL Fiddle is awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` like:

```
INSERT INTO myCTGlobalFootprint (geoName)
select 'Canada'
UNION
select 'United States'
UNION
select 'Europe'
UNION
select 'International Misc.';
```

Otherwise you have to write four `INSERT INTO` statements like:

```
INSERT INTO myCTGlobalFootprint(geoName) VALUES('Canada');
INSERT INTO myCTGlobalFootprint(geoName) VALUES('United States');
INSERT INTO myCTGlobalFootprint(geoName) VALUES('Europe');
INSERT INTO myCTGlobalFootprint(geoName) VALUES('International Misc.');
```

Comment: This would be true in other databases, but MySQL provides an extension which allows a single insert statement to provide values for multiple rows; the syntax posted by OP will work in MySQL. It's not mandatory that this be re-written as four separate insert statements.

Comment: That's right @spencer7593, there is no need to write it in 4 different insert queries or even to use UNION when you can use just comma .